# Infering the mean distance from density

Tags: density, mean-free-path

A simple calculation surely but how we can infer the mean distance $l_{\text{mean}}$ between particles from their density $n$, i.e :

$$l_{\text{mean}}=\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{1/3}$$

?

I tried to visualize it for example into a cube : by taking $n=8$, we would have $l_{\text{mean}} =0.5$, so equal to the half side length of cube but we must have 8 particles. How to take a right example ?

Maybe I should consider instead no $n$ but $\bar{n}$, or the representation by a cube is not appropriate, I don't know. Is there a mathematical justification for mean path $l_{\text{mean}}$?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Make a drawing. It is exactly 8 sub-cubic of side length equal to half the side length of the big cube.

Comment: @ytlu . Thanks for your quick answer. For example, If I take 4 big cubes and a particle in the center of each of it, I would get 4 particles for 32 sub-cubic, so a density of 4/32 = 1/8 particle /sub-cubic (0.5x0.5x05), is it right ? but how to justify the distance between the distance between 2 particles of 2 adjacents sub-cubic which is equal to 0.5+0.5 = 1 and not 0.5 ? Best regards

Comment: @ytlu I think trouble of my understanding is that I have got to think as mean distance but I don't know how to express it from a mathematical point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$Density=\frac{mass\,or\,no.\,of\,particles}{Total\,Volume\,occupied\,by\,all\,these\,particles}$$

Hence if I invert it I get the Volume occupied by a single particle. So assuming these particles occupy a cubical volume with cube side $l_{mean}$ on average,
$$l_{mean}^3=\frac{Total\,volume}{Total\,Number}=\frac{1}{Density}$$

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning behind this formula is indeed the cubic lattice. It is necessary however to stress that this formula is just *an estimate* rather than a precise calculation.

- Firstly, because molecules/atoms are not necessarily located at the nodes of a cubic lattice.
- Secondly, even if it were the case, there are obvious *boundary effects* which depend on how we choose the volume. Think of an infinite cubic lattice and try to choose a cubic volume, enclosing 8 molecules (lattice sites). One sees that the side of this cubic volume may range from just a bit more than two lattice spacings to nearly four lattice spacings, still enclosing only 8 molecules, but producing rather different density values. However, if we compare with the cubes enclosing $3^3=27$ molecules, $4^3=64$ molecules, $5^3=125$ molecules and so on, we see that the relative error in density decreases, as the number of enclosed molecules increases. When we get to as much as anAvogadro number of molecules, this error is negligeable, and the equation $$l=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/3}$$ becomes nearly exact (just like all the thermodynamical relations, which are exact only in the *thermodynamical limit*).